# Updating mysql code using select command

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

So I have an assignment that is asking for me to add data into a table using the SELECT command. I've always known to use the insert into command or the Update command so I'm a little confused.

There are 2 tables, one named 'Book' and one named 'Fiction'. Book already has data in the table, I need to insert values from book into fiction using the select tool.

If someone could help explain it would be great,

Thank you!

Comment: You are probably asked to use an insert select: `insert into my table (col1, col2) select c1, c2 from other_table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the assignment means, is to still use a `INSERT` query, but with an `SELECT` query attached to insert rows quickly from one table to another.

> With INSERT ... SELECT, you can quickly insert many rows into a table
>   from the result of a SELECT statement, which can select from one or
>   many tables. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

> Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I seeeeee! I was so confused! okay thank you so much